# Typescript error when giving const variable interface

Tags: typescript

```js
 const feedingItem: Notification = feedingPageNotifications.find(
    (notification: Notification) => notification.id === index
  )
```

```js
export interface Notification {
  priority: number
  id: number
  title: string
  description: string
  buttonText: string
  backgroundImage: number
  displayName?: boolean
  backgroundColor: string
}
```

feedingItem is doing what I want so, I can type feedingItem.title for example and it autocompletes and does type checks but for some reason I got a error below const feedingItem saying:

```
Type '{ priority: number; id: number; title: string; description: string; buttonText: string; backgroundColor: string; backgroundImage: any; displayName?: undefined; } | { priority: number; id: number; ... 5 more ...; backgroundImage: any; } | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Notification'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Notification'.ts(2322)
```

What's the reason for this error?

Comment: `find` can return undefined if none of the array items match the given predicate

Comment: Just remove `Notification` from ` const feedingItem: Notification`. Like @Joonas said, TS will infer it to `Notification | undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at the type signature of `Array.find` which looks something like this:

```
find(
  predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => unknown,
  thisArg?: any
): T | undefined;
```

As you can see, it returns `T | undefined`. That's because it's possible that no items in the array match the predicate that you provide to `find`.